# Threejs, why “Texture marked for update but image is incomplete”?

Tags: three.js

i use 256*256 pixels png as texture, and the geometry.vertices is also 256*256.
it comes out the warning "Texture marked for update but image is incomplete".
maybe i do not understand the meaning of "incomplete".
thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you load the texture. So this is just my guess.

I can see this line in setTexture2D.

```
} else if ( image.complete === false ) {
    console.warn( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is incomplete', texture );
} else {
```

I suppose your texture.image is not yet loaded. How are you loading the image? If you load texture.image like below and don't handle image.onload to wait using it till it's properly put on memory, I guess this warning could happen.

```
var texture = new Texture();
texture.image = new Image();
document.body.appendChild(texture.image);
texture.image.src = "http://......../texture.png";
```

If so, I'd recommend using THREE.TextureLoader instead and make sure the texture is loaded before using it.